# How to rewrite that code in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I have below code and i what to rewrite it with RxJava approach. `method`, `stringsRepo.getStrings` and `objectsRepo.getObjects` should return Observables

```
private ObjectsCollection method(){
    HashMap<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> strings = stringsRepo.getStrings();
    for (String string : strings) {
        map.put(string, objectsRepo.getObjects(string));
    }
    return new ObjectCollection(map);
}
```

I rewrote it as follows:

```
  public Observable<HashMap<String, List<Object>>> getObjects() {
    return getStrings().flatMap(Observable::from)
            .collect(HashMap::new, (Action2<HashMap<String, List<Object>>, String>) (map, s) ->
                    getObjects(s).subscribe(objectList -> map.put(s, objectList)));
}

private Observable<List<String>> getStrings(){
    return Observable.just(new ArrayList<>());
}
private Observable<List<Object>> getObjects(String string){
    return Observable.just(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Is there a more correct way to do it?

Comment: Why do you want this as Rx? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Also - what have you tried so far?

Comment: I just started learning Rx and want to rewrite this basic example using rx, but cant understand how to combine result of strings and related objects to one observable of hashmap

Comment: In that case it would definitely help to show what you have so far so we can build on that and get a better idea of your level of understanding

Comment: I did update with my solution

Comment: What is `getStrings` returning?

Comment: Observable<List<String>>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138533/discussion-between-niks-stack-and-tddmonkey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the `collect` operator:

```
Observable
.fromIterable(stringsRepo.getStrings())
.collect(() -> new HashMap<String,List<String>>(), 
         (map, string) -> map.put(string, objectsRepo.getObjects(string)))
.blockingSubscribe()
.first();
```

However, that's not a good use of RxJava - it could just as well be written in the Java 8 streams API.

Comment: I'm writing for Android, but it's does not support Java 8

Comment: You can trivially replace the lambdas with anonymous classes.